# No route matches [POST] "/user/1/cars"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller

on my app i have this
i'm trying to create a car of a previously registered user
but i got the error (tittle post)
this is my carcontroller

```
class CarController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @car = Car.new
    end

    def create
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @car = @user.car.create(params[:car])
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    end
end
```

this is my route.rb

```
Estaciones::Application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users

root :to => "user#index"
resources :user do
   resources :cars
end

get "user/new"
post "user/create"
get "user/:id" => "User#show"
get "user/:user_id/car/new"
```

and this is part of my html.erb

```
<div class="container">

  <h1>new user registered</h1>

  <p>
    <strong>name:</strong>
    <%= @user.name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>email:</strong>
    <%= @user.email %>
  </p>

  <h2>new car registration</h2>

  <%= form_for([@user, @user.car.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :brand %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :brand %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :color %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :color %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :model %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :model %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :year %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :year %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit "Create new car"%>
     </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

when i submit the creation of the new car i got the next error

```
No route matches [POST] "/user/1/cars"
```

any idea??

also my routes:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
   cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                devise/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  devise/registrations#edit
                     PUT    /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#destroy
                root        /                                      user#index
           user_cars GET    /user/:user_id/cars(.:format)          cars#index
                     POST   /user/:user_id/cars(.:format)          cars#create
        new_user_car GET    /user/:user_id/cars/new(.:format)      cars#new
       edit_user_car GET    /user/:user_id/cars/:id/edit(.:format) cars#edit
            user_car GET    /user/:user_id/cars/:id(.:format)      cars#show
                     PUT    /user/:user_id/cars/:id(.:format)      cars#update
                     DELETE /user/:user_id/cars/:id(.:format)      cars#destroy
          user_index GET    /user(.:format)                        user#index
                     POST   /user(.:format)                        user#create
            new_user GET    /user/new(.:format)                    user#new
           edit_user GET    /user/:id/edit(.:format)               user#edit
                user GET    /user/:id(.:format)                    user#show
                     PUT    /user/:id(.:format)                    user#update
                     DELETE /user/:id(.:format)                    user#destroy
            user_new GET    /user/new(.:format)                    user#new
         user_create POST   /user/create(.:format)                 user#create
                     GET    /user/:id(.:format)                    User#show
                     GET    /user/:user_id/cars/new(.:format)      car#new
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a ruby on rails person. But....
your post url `/users/1/cars` does not match any of the routes you mentioned in your `route.rb` file.

Comment: how can i fix it please any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :

```
root :to => "user#index"
resources :users do
  resources :cars
end
```

Instead this :

```
root :to => "user#index"
resources :user do
  resources :cars
end
```

(add a s to user). And try to go here : /users/1/cars

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `resources :user` is singular, but the route wants a plural. The routes should be:

```
resources :users do
  resources :cars
end
```